# Does this distance measure have a name?

Tags: measure-theory, graph-theory, vector-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

I'm looking for discussion / literature recommendations of a (possibly slightly weird) measure function: perhaps a weighted version of taxicab distance? This is not really my area and so I'd be super grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Suppose I have a space $[0, 1]^n$, so vectors $\textbf{v}$ are just n-tuples with either 0 or 1 for each $v_i \in \textbf{v}$.

Then we define the distance $D$ between $\textbf{v}, \textbf{u}$ as follows:

$$D(\textbf{v}, \textbf{u}) = \sum_{i}^{n} d(v_i, u_i)$$

where crucially: $d(1, 0) \neq d(0, 1)$. Informally, the idea is going 'up' from zero to one can be more (or less) easy than going down from one to zero.

Is this a well-known distance measure? Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: But this cannot be a true metric, because the symmetry condition is violated:  $D(a,b) = D(b,a)\ \forall \{ a, b \}$.  Also, the triangle requirement need not be obeyed:  $D(a,b) + D(b,c) \geq D(a,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

But this cannot be a true metric, because the symmetry condition is violated:  $D(a,b) = D(b,a)\ \forall \{ a, b \}$.  Also, the triangle requirement need not be obeyed:  $D(a,b) + D(b,c) \geq D(a,c)$.